# How to create Association-Flow in Fluent BPMN API?

Tags: java, fluent, bpmn

I use Eclipse bpmn2 plugin to modelize my workflow
:

[image]

[image]

I use [Fluent](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/fluent-builder-api/) BPMN API to draw my Diagram programmatically.

Question:

How can we create an **Association-Flow** (not sequential-flow) in [Fluent](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/fluent-builder-api/) to draw something like this :
[image]